# Paste, overwriting selection from clipboard, and copy selection

Tags: copy-paste

I am wondering if there is a way to select text, paste the current clipboard to overwrite the selection, but concurrently copy the selected text to the clipboard.

I basically have two values in a document that I want to swap between variable assignment, without having to copy and move the first, then copy and move the second in place.

Context: MacOS, in chrome, but hoping for a generic answer.

Comment: What Operating System? What program?

Comment: Right, updated the question. Was hoping for maybe a generic/universal solution, but there probably is no such thing :/

Comment: [How to Have Multiple Items for Copy and Paste on Mac](https://www.gizmotimes.com/tips-tricks/mac-os-x/multiple-items-copy-paste-mac/15077)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I was hoping for a stock solution to basically "swap" values in and out of the clipboard, but this may be a more robust solution

Comment: You would need some kind of add-on, script, or key assignment to perform the sequence of events.